# How multiple .so file added in ldconfig?

Tags: root, shared-library, syslinux, dynamic-linking

[image]

`librcdev.so.1.6`, `librcdev.so.1` and `librcdev.so` files are linked with
`librcdev.so.1.6.0` .

I updated `ldconfig` but after:

```
ldconfig -p | grep librcdev
```

All `.so` files are not showing.

(all `.so` files are located in `/usr/local/lib`)

Comment: I can't get what is the problem... Are you asking why there are multiple links to a library? or why your library cache is empty?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . why library cache is empty?

Comment: What is the output of `ldconfig -p | wc -l` ?

Comment: Another question is that after 'ldconfig -p | grep librcdev' ,I got only librcdev.so.1 and librcdev.so . Why i am not getting librcdev.so.1.6 and  librcdev.so.1.6.0 ? (i got 1198) @Ravexina

Comment: Please edit your question and add your exact problem.

Comment: @ Ravexina : 1198